# Printing an stdClass object

Tags: php, wordpress, stdclass

I have:

```
$value = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT custom_message FROM `wp_wpsc_cart_contents` WHERE purchaseid='" . $purchase_log['id'] . "'");
```

if I do:

```
print_r($value);
```

I get:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [custom_message] =>  |Castor Seed Oil  $4.45| 
)
```

So I tried to get that value doing:

```
foreach($value as $index => $result) {
   echo $result["custom_message"];
}
```

I also tried:

```
foreach($value as $index => $result) {
   echo $result->custom_message;
}
```

but that prints nothing, any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop does nothing, you are iterating an object with a single property that you already know the name of. Just do this:

```
echo $value->custom_message;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `for` loop. Just do

```
  echo $value->custom_message;
```