# Printing stdClass Object value

Tags: php, object, echo, stdclass

I know similar sort of questions been asked before. But reason I'm asking is because I have tried many of those solution provided here in those questions, but nothing seemed to work for me. :( Let's say I have tried these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497729/printing-an-stdclass-object)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688650/php-array-stdclass-object-echo-value)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813225/how-can-i-access-an-object-property)

**Background**

I'm calling to a RESTAPI and get data in json format.

```
$apiResult  = connect_to_api($link); // function works fine

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r(json_decode($apiResult));
echo '</pre>';
```

when I print, I get following result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 91
    [name_1] => city name
    [name_2] => area name
    [name_3] => municipality
    [web] => www.example.com
)
```

**Problem Scope**

When I try to access only value of `id` it says trying to get non-object property. Like for example I tried

```
echo $apiResult->id;

foreach($apiResult as $result){
    echo $result->id;
}
```

Nothing did really work. Don't know where am I going wrong. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just make it an array insted of an object  `json_decode($apiResult,true)`

Comment: @Mihai Why would people want to convert a perfectly good object into an array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Why not?

Comment: @Mihai Why? What is the point. Are you afraid of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try to decode the json before calling the object property?

```
$apiResult = json_decode(connect_to_api($link));
echo $apiResult->id;
```

Comment: @Mihai, yes I did decode before calling the object property. foreach(json_decode($apiResult) as $result){
    echo $result->id;
}
but didn't work though.

Comment: The result is not an array but a simple object.. try it like I did to see if works

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach you are basically processing over the objects properties and getting the properties returned as a name => value pair.

So in this statement of your :-

```
foreach($apiResult as $result){
    echo $result->id;
}
```

`$result` will be `91`, `city name`, `area name` .... i.e. the values of each property and not an object at all.

So for example if you coded the foreach like this it would demonstrate this

```
// foreach over the object
foreach ( $apiResult as $property => $Value ) {
    echo "Property Name =  $property";
    echo " Property Value = $value <br>";
}
```

But this is unlikely to be what you want to do, I assume you just want to get at the properties by name, so use

```
echo $apiResult->id;
echo $apiResult->name_1;

etc
```